# Lua / Coroutines How to measures how much memory standard functions take

Tags: memory, memory-management, lua, stack, coroutine

i'm currently trying to find a way to return a static value which would represent how much memory standart a function takes or its time of execution (as a static thread), I thought about using coroutines, however I cannot make any working prototypes, thanks for help in advance ! (:

Comment: Your use of the term "static" makes me think of C/C++. Are you implementing this with Lua's C API?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what I wanted to mean is I need to retrieve a constant value, that will not change depending of the context, to be able to do some benchmarks

Answer (score 0):

The Lua function `collectgarbage` with the string `"count"` as an argument returns a number that reflects the amount of memory currently in use by the interpreter. Here is a [link](http://luatut.com/collectgarbage.html) to an example and more information; I will reproduce the example here:

```
function memuse()
    local i = math.modf(collectgarbage("count") * 1024)
    return i
end
```

This function returns the amount of memory, in kilobytes, currently in use by Lua.

As for time, the simplest way is to call `os.time()`, which returns the current system time. Note, though, that this only returns the number of seconds to the nearest whole number. If you need greater precision, there are a few options: one, place a system call with `io.popen` to retrieve the current system time, which includes the non-integer portion; or two, implement some time-related functions in C/C++ and call them from Lua. I have used both options and the second one produces excellent accuracy, but for the sake of simplicity I will just show the first one.

```
-- Function called 'tick' to retrieve the current OS time.
function tick()
    local fil = assert(io.popen("date +%s.%N"))
    local str = fil:read("*all")
    return tonumber(str)
end
```

Lua file handles--one of which is produced by the call to `io.popen`--have their own destructors so they need not be explicitly closed; however, you may want to call `fil:close()` for the sake of garbage collection and avoiding any open file-related errors.

If you want to pursue the second, more complicated option, I suggest creating a timer class in C++ that makes use of the `chrono` library to retrieve the system time.

I am not sure that these two functions are of relevance to you, but I hope they help.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer I really appreciate it. Actually I know those functions to retrieve memory and such, but what I more precisely wanted to do is (I don't know how) returning a constant value of the memory usage a random function takes, I planned using that as a detour finder, for example checking the memory usage debug.getinfo should normally uses, and then being able to find a detoured function by comparing with a marge. Because right now using the garbage collection on a function returns two total different results if launched many times.

Comment: @Alexandra My knowledge of Lua's debug library is one area in which I am lacking, but, as I understand it, `debug.getinfo` provides information about the number of upvalues a function has but it gives nothing about how much memory a function actually consumes. When looking at C--Lua's implementation language--there is no way to know the size of a function, unless one knows, with absolute certainty, that two functions are contiguous in memory and thus the size of one can be computed using pointers. Based on this, I do not know if it is possible to find the amount of memory a Lua function uses.